# How to force geth node to propagate stuck transaction, or abort them

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, txpool

I have several transactions from the same address stuck in geth node and not visible in mempool via etherscan (transactions from other addresses are sent to blockchain ok)

Those transactions are stuck in the node for more than 24 hours, although node configuration  --txpool.lifetime value is set to 24h0m0s.

Is there any way either to force node to propagate those transactions to the blockchain, or to clean them up from node (to be able to resend without double spending)?

Regards, 
Leonid

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is, transferring all ether from the account, which signed the "stuck" transaction, to another account. However, this time I would set a higher gas price, so the "stuck" transaction would look like double spending :)